# Convert 3 consecutive number in a string with a symbol

Tags: python

I was trying to change every 3 consecutive numbers in string with "@" symbol.
I don't mean 1.2.3 , but every 3 numbers .

```
input ="kJF534kdfkj23kk222"
```

Desired output :

```
output="kJF@@@kdfkj23kk@@@"
```

I'm a beginner in Python and I didn't know how to do that.

I tried the following but I'm having trouble in my for loop.

```
if i.isdigit() and (i+1).isdigit() and (i+2).isdigit():
    output = input.replace(i, "@")
    output=input.replace(i+1,"@")
    output=input.replace(i+2,"@")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use regular expressions:

```
import re

s = "kJF534kdfkj23kk222"
out = re.sub(r"\d{3}","@@@", s)
print(out)
```

output:

```
"kJF@@@kdfkj23kk@@@"
```

This will match every sequence of 3 consecutive digits (`\d` match a digit, `{3}` indicates a sequence of 3) and replace them with `@@@`